# crawling next page when url remains same

Tags: python, web-crawler

I need some help to crawl the data from the url below
https://onland.kbstar.com/quics?page=C060250&keyword=%EB%8F%99%EC%9E%91%EA%B5%AC

I would like to crawl the second page but the url remains the same when I click '2' and don't know how to do it. Please help!

Here's my python code to crawl the fist page :

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request as req
import urllib
import re
from datetime import datetime
import requests
```

```
dataframe = pd.DataFrame()
```

```
def KB_liveON(area_name):

    query = area_name
    area = urllib.parse.quote(query)

    url = 'https://onland.kbstar.com' \
        + '/quics?page=C060250' \
        + '&keyword=' + str(area) 
    #    + '#CP'

    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

    table = soup.find('table')
    trs = table.tbody.find_all('tr')
    dataframe = pd.DataFrame()
    value_list = []

    for tr in trs[::1]:
        tds = tr.find_all('td')
        #cols = [' '.join(td.text.strip().split()) for td in tds]
        cols = [td.text.strip().split() for td in tds]
        progress = cols[0]
        location = cols[1]
        complex_name = cols[2]
        area = cols[3]
        sale_price = cols[4]
        sale_price2 = cols[5]
        time = cols[6]
        type_of_sale = cols[7]
        construction_company = cols[8]

        value_list.append([progress ,location, complex_name ,area, sale_price, sale_price2, time, type_of_sale, construction_company])

        cols = ['progress' ,'location','complex_name' ,'area','sale_price','sale_price2','time','type_of_sale','construction_company']
        df = pd.DataFrame(value_list, columns=cols)
    return df
```

```
kb = KB_liveON('동작구')

dataframe = dataframe.append(kb)
dataframe
```

Comment: Find the `2` then click on it

Comment: Also, you have `selenium`, for the page with dynamic generate using JS, you need to use selenium to open up a web driver since your req get the web page but not generate content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I install a Selenium WebDriver on Google Colab. Then I write a crawler to crawl data from multiple pages.

Python code:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)

def extract_data(value_list, html_tags):
  soup = BeautifulSoup(html_tags, 'lxml')

  table = soup.find('table')
  trs = table.tbody.find_all('tr')

  for tr in trs[::1]:
      tds = tr.find_all('td')
      cols = [td.text.strip().split() for td in tds]
      progress = cols[0]
      location = cols[1]
      complex_name = cols[2]
      area = cols[3]
      sale_price = cols[4]
      sale_price2 = cols[5]
      time = cols[6]
      type_of_sale = cols[7]
      construction_company = cols[8]
      value_list.append([progress ,location, complex_name ,area, sale_price, sale_price2, time, type_of_sale, construction_company])
  return value_list

def KB_liveON(area):
  url = 'https://onland.kbstar.com' \
          + '/quics?page=C060250' \
          + '&keyword=' + str(area) 

  wd.get(url)

  data_list = []

  # Extract data from first page
  tbl = wd.find_elements_by_class_name("tbl_list")[0]
  html_tags = tbl.get_attribute('outerHTML')
  data_list = extract_data(data_list, html_tags)

  # Find and extract data from other pages except first page
  forms = wd.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='paging']//form")

  for f in forms[1:]:
    f.submit()
    time.sleep(10)
    tbl = wd.find_elements_by_class_name("tbl_list")[0]
    html_tags = tbl.get_attribute('outerHTML')
    data_list = extract_data(data_list, html_tags)
    time.sleep(10)

  cols = ['progress' ,'location','complex_name' ,'area','sale_price','sale_price2','time','type_of_sale','construction_company']
  df = pd.DataFrame(data_list, columns=cols)
  return df

if __name__=='__main__':
  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  options.add_argument('--headless')
  options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
  options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

  wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver', options=options)

  df = KB_liveON('동작구')
  print (df)
```

Output (The crawl results):
[image]